# How can I generate (email) alerts everytime the postgres superuser logs in to postgres database

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, database-administration

I'm looking to be alerted (via email) anytime someone logs in to a production postgres database as the superuser.

This seems like a common use case but I haven't much online as to the best way to do this.

Comment: You could turn on logging of connections and then have a file watcher (shell script) grepping the Postgres log file for the respective log lines

Comment: This seems plausible can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen logon triggers on commercial databases, but not on PostgreSQL. Here you just have to protect your superuser password better, I guess ;-)

Just an idea: you can track logons to SSH, so if you can force the superusers to log on through an SSH tunnel, you may just have a way to send the e-mail.